# Is there an equivalent of the DebuggerStepThrough Attribute in VB6

Tags: debugging, vb6

I'm looking for a way to have the equivalent of the DebuggerStepThrough attribute in the VB6 IDE.
 There are methods (trace methods for example) I know, I won't need to step in.

I know I can use the Shortcut Shift-F8 to step over but when debugging a long method, it's not practical to switch form F8 to Shift-F8

Comment: No direct equivalent. You have to swap out the function to a compiled (referenced) binary component not to step into it w/ F8.